# TTG Minecraft Story Mode cloud saves fail

Tags: technical-issues, ios, android, minecraft-story-mode

I have played Story Mode on 5 iOS devices and 2 android devices. On all devices I am unable to get cloud saving to work. One device I was initially able to enable it but it never works (when saving there is a red x on the cloud indicating failed save).

My internet is not an issue. I'm able to use other game feature that use the internet.

Has anybody else experienced this and know how to fix it?

Issue occurs on iOS 9.0.2 and 9.1 (no jailbreaks). I forgot the android version but I think it's 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

The iOS problem is likely caused by you not having enough iCloud space.

To check your iCloud space go to settings > Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes Store (At the top under your name) > iCloud > manage storage.

Also make sure backup is enabled for Minecraft story mode.